# Simple PHP echo does not function?

Tags: php, function, echo

I am having issues with my code. I am pretty certain that it is related to quotations. Let me demonstrate.

This works fine:

```
<?php if ( $is_latest_post ) echo '
hello world
'; ?>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<?php if ( $is_latest_post ) echo '
<a class="recent<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/<?php echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></a>
'; ?>
```

Why doesn't it work? What can I change to make it function? The `a class` part of the code works perfectly outside the `if ( $is_latest_post )` statement. Appreciate that I have only just started learning coding with PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? It doesn't output anything? Or not what you expect it to output?

Comment: Why all the nested <?php ?> tags?

Comment: Maybe you should 'view source' in the browser. the echo is most likely working however whatever you have put in the anchor text isn't.

Comment: @andrewsi I updated my question. It gives an error. But the code works perfectly outside the if statement.

Comment: @SabeenMalik No, it gives an error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you encapsulate strings in single quotes, it treats that string as a literal.  PHP will not parse the code you have in that string.

What you need is concatenation.  The dot operator `.` lets you mash several strings together.

```
<?
if ( $is_latest_post ) {
    $category = get_the_category();
    echo '
    <a class="recent' . $category[0]->category_nicename . '" href="' . bloginfo('url') . '/'. $category[0]->category_nicename . '">' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</a>';
}
?>
```

You can concatenate arbitrarily many things together.

```
<?
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2.0;
    $c = 'string';
    $d = function_call();

    $string = $a . $b . 'random text' . $c . $d;

?>
```

Comment: Can you kindly write up the entire code so that I can test if it works?

Comment: I just tested your code, it returned an error. Maybe you had a typo somewhere? The error was: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in**

Comment: T_ENDWHILE implies there is a while loop somewhere in your code.  The code I have given you works when I substitute dummy values.  You must have a typo elsewhere.

Comment: Yes this code is executed in a loop. What can I do to make it work within that loop? The code works perfectly outside the IF statement.

Comment: Making it work inside of a loop is a different question and problem.  I presume you will need to replace `$category[0]` with `$category[$i]` or similar.  If you don't know how to write a loop, I would suggest reading the php manual.

Comment: I changed it to $i as you suggested but nothing returned. Thank you regardless for your assistance.

Comment: `$i` is only appropriate if that is the counter used in your loop.  If nothing is printing out, there is likely a different semantic problem.  As others have pointed out, if `$is_latest_post` is not true, the echo statement will not execute.

Comment: @Kevin My apologies. You are very correct, I made a typo. I have executed your code properly now, everything works besides the **bloginfo('url')**. That echo's outside of the a tag. Do you know why?

Comment: I assumed `bloginfo()` returned a string.  If instead it directly echos data, it will not appear correctly.  Concatenation of functions works if it returns a string.

Comment: I see, so I will not be able to use it this way then?

Comment: Cheers regardless for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?
    if ( $is_latest_post ) {
        $category = get_the_category();
        echo "<a class=\"recent" . $category[0]->category_nicename . "href=\"" . bloginfo('url') . "/". $category[0]->category_nicename. "\">" .$category[0]->cat_name."</a>";
}
    ?>
```

In addition to Kevin's answer, I prefer using double quote instead of single quote and escape it when needed.

Comment: Indeed, single quotes used to give better performance; now it's just a force of habit.

Comment: Just don't tell that to the ones that are obsessed with micro performance :D :D

Comment: Cheers, however this still does not solve my issue as the same error is being displayed. How do I execute this within a loop...?

Comment: I would guess that you need to replace $category[0]->category_nicename with $category[i]->category_nicename, where i is the loop counter.

Comment: It would help if you posted the loop - as is you issue is a mystery to us.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute php code within a string literal. Browsers won't display empty tags, since there is nothing to render within them.

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes for starters. This will never evaluate any php code - it will just print it out.

**Edit**: If blogInfo() returns a string (return $somevar) then use the code below.

```
<?php

if ( $is_latest_post ) 
{
    $category = get_the_category(); 
    $template = '<a class="recent%s" href="%s/%s">%s</a>';
    $blogInfo = bloginfo('url');

    echo sprintf(
        $template,
        $category[0]->category_nicename,
        $bloginfo,
        $category[0]->category_nicename,
        $category[0]->cat_name
    );
}
?>
```

If blogInfo() echos data on screen (echo $somevar) then use the code below.

```
<?php

if ( $is_latest_post ) 
{
    $category = get_the_category(); 
    $prefix   = '<a class="recent%s" href="';
    $suffix   = '/%s">%s</a>';

    echo sprintf(
        $prefix,
        $category[0]->category_nicename,
    );

    bloginfo('url');

    echo sprintf(
        $suffix,
        $category[0]->category_nicename,
        $category[0]->cat_name
    );
}
?>
```

[sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) allows you to "inject" a variable in a template.

I would strongly suggest you revisit your code and try to make it as simple as possible. Having a bunch of assignments and function calls in the presentation layer (i.e. the echo) will make your code very hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: I tested your code and got this error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE**. This code is executed in a loop. What will I need to change to make it work there?

Comment: I forgot the closing bracket for the if statement, which I noticed and corrected. Please test it again if you don't mind.

Comment: I just tested it again, it did not return an error but it did not return anything else either. Empty.

Comment: `$template` must be passed as the first parameter to `sprintf`.

Comment: In that case, what is the value of $is_latest_post ? If it is not true  then the block of code will never execute.

Comment: Bah. Thanks Kevin - brain fade there. Gary, please check it again if you don't mind.

Comment: Tested it again, did not work properly, the A tag did not come through and other parts of the code. It only returned a URL. What is missing in the code?

Comment: Gary, I changed the code based on comments above. If bloginfo('url') outputs the code directly i.e. echo "blabla"; then use the second example, otherwise the first. HTH